# CakePHP alias breaks HABTM Model

Tags: php, cakephp, alias, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-model

Consider the following HABTM relation in CakePHP 2.2.3:

```
class User extends AppModel
{    
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Role' => array(
            'className' => 'Role',
            'joinTable' => 'roles_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'role_id',
        )

    );
}
```

This works fine, but when using an alias like `VeryUniqueAlias` instead of `Role` and changing the UsersController accordingly, the m:n relation is not persisted in the database (the data passed to `save()` in the controller are equivalent).

This does not work:

```
class User extends AppModel
{    
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'VeryUniqueAlias' => array(
            'className' => 'Role',
            'joinTable' => 'roles_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'role_id',
        )

    );
}
```

This is awkward, since the the [CakePHP docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#relationship-types) state that it should work.
Any idea why it's not working for me? Did I miss something?

Comment: Had this problem before, also using containable and getting errors saying User is not associated with VeryUniqueAlias. Never found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'with' key to define the name of the model for the join table. In your case:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'VeryUniqueAlias' => array(
        'className' => 'Role',
        'joinTable' => 'roles_users',
        'with' => 'RolesUser',    // first model pluralized
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'role_id',
    )

);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Wow, bummer on the down vote. Adding the 'with' key has helped me when I've had similar problems.

Comment: Don't know who downvoted and don't understand why. Thanks anyway.